# grails spring-security create user

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy, spring-security

Im having some problems creating new user from one of my controllers. I'm trying to add a new user to my MongoDB user collection like this. Authorities is defined as a Set of Role in the domain.

```
Role role = new Role(authority:"ROLE_USER")
User user = new User(username:params.username,email:params.email,password:params.password,enabled:params.enabled,
            accountExpired:params.accountExpired,accountLocked:params.accountLocked,passwordExpired:params.passwordExpired,
            authorities:[role])

if (user.validate()) {
        user.save(flush:true)
      } else {
        user.errors.allErrors.each { println it }
      }
```

The exact same code is able to create a user successfully from the bootstrap, but when i'm trying to do the same thing from a simple controller i'm getting this error:

```
2012-09-24 10:43:27,450 [http-8080-3] ERROR binding.GrailsDataBinder  - Unable to auto-create type interface java.util.Set, class java.lang.InstantiationException thrown in constructor
```

a:662)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with data binding. You have to create User with authorities first and then add role using UserRole domain. Something like:

```
Role role = Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_USER")
User user = new User(username:params.username,email:params.email,password:params.password,enabled:params.enabled,     accountExpired:params.accountExpired,accountLocked:params.accountLocked,passwordExpired:params.passwordExpired)
new UserRole(user: user, role: role).save(flush: flush, insert: true)
user.save(flush:true)
```

For more information how to create user with spring security, you may want to look at [Spring Security UI](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ui)

Comment: This might be correct when using the native support of databases. However it seems like the connection towards the MongoDB which is achieved by fiddling your detailService does not really care about the UserRole properties in that fashion for this question. However im am able to save my items now, but im running into some other problems atm.